# В профиле появилась доп функция (bbp_keymaster), как ее удалить?

Tags: wordpress

Ранее я такой функции не видела в своем профиле админа сайта.
Что она дает? И как ее убрать?[image: фото1]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72830/discussion-on-question-by-chernikova------bbp-keymas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что она дает?

Это возможность от BBPress

> И как ее убрать?

С помощью какого-нибудь плагина для управления ролями и их возможностями.  Выбирать актуальные тут: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/capability

Comment: не помогло :(((

Comment: Что значит "непомогло"? Само ничего и не поможет. Нужно найти подходящий плагин и с **его помощью** удалить не нужную возможность. Самостоятельно.

Comment: именно это и не помогло. читайте выше комменты мои. и плагин по очистке не помог. ничего не помогло. кроме ручного поиска данной строчки в БД

Comment: Совет лазить в базу - очень плохой совет. То, что просто перестало показываться у юзера. это как заклеить обоями  треснувшую стену. Проблемы не видно, и ладно.

Comment: иными вариантами и не убиралось. может это и был единственный "след" от bbpress'а в БД. там почти вся строчка иначе была написана. я ее переписала аналогично своему тестовому сайту на вордпресс. где еще не было bbpress установки.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте данный код в **function.php**

```
  remove_filter( 'bbp_get_keymaster_role', 'bbp_keymaster', 10, 1 );
```

**[remove_filter](https://wp-kama.ru/function/remove_filter)** - Удаляет указанную функцию прикрепленную к указанному фильтру.

**[bbp_keymaster](http://hookr.io/filters/bbp_get_keymaster_role/)** - Роль пользователя в [BBPress](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/bbpress/).